# Issue Updating Vue 3 Component State After Asynchronous Operation

Tags: javascript, vue.js, state, pinia

In my Vue 3 based app, I'm facing challenges in updating the state of a component after an asynchronous operation. Here's the scenario:

In a component, I have a method containerMoveHere that performs an asynchronous operation using Socket.io to move a container which gets added to the list of containers that are displayed. After the move operation is successful, I want to update the children array in my Pinia store and ensure that my component re-renders to reflect the updated state.

Here's my code:

page.vue

```
<template>
...
<div class="flex justify-end space-x-2">
     <MoveToHereButton @click.prevent="containerMoveHere()" />
</div>
...
<div class="grid grid-cols-3 gap-4 py-6 place-content-stretch">
   <div v-for="child in children" :key="child._id">
      <ContainerCard :container="child" />
   </div>
</div>
...
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">

const userStore = useUserStore();
const containerStore = useContainerStore()
const container = storeToRefs(containerStore).container;
const children = storeToRefs(containerStore).visibleChildren;

async function containerMoveHere() {
  try {
    let containerStrId = await userStore.getContainerIdToMove();
    await containerStore.containerMoveHere(containerStrId)
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
  }
}


</script>
```

And this is my store:

```
export const useContainerStore = defineStore('container', {
  state: () => {
    let container: iContainerAllType | undefined;
    const children: Array<{ visible: boolean; data: iContainerAllType }> = [];
    return { 
      container, children 
    };
  },
  getters: {
    visibleChildren(): Array<iContainerAllType> {
      return this.children.filter(c => c.visible).map(c => c.data);
    }
  },
  actions: {
   async containerMoveHere(sourceContainerStrId) {
      try {
        await socketioservice.emit('container:moveTo', {
          container: {
            Id: this.container?._id,
            Space: this.container?._space,
            SourceId: sourceContainerStrId 
            }
        });
      } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error moving container:', error);
        }
      },
   }
```

Further context:

The move of the container is successful. If I reload the page, the added container gets displayed properly within the children.

The issue is that the children state does not get updated even though children is a reactive property.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: in `page.vue` you've created a function `containerMoveHere` ...but you never call it ... not even sure what `containerMoveHere` in your store is supposed to achieve

Comment: @JaromandaX There's a button on the navbar which calls the function. Basically, the function moves a container not originally present on the page, to the page.

Comment: @JaromandaX code for the button calling the function is now added to my question. Thanks for pointing out it was missing.

Comment: The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . You don't update children anywhere.

Comment: @EstusFlask I have tried adding children.value = containerStore.visibleChildren after the await containerStore.containerMoveHere(containerStrId) within the async function containerMoveHere(), but it still doesn't work and in the console I see the warning "reactivity.esm-bundler.js:1167 Write operation failed: computed value is readonly"

Comment: It doesn't make sense to assign a getter, it's read-only, not to mention that children.value is the same as visibleChildren. Please, explain what you're trying to do and how. The question lacks clear problem statement. Currently you don't change state.children anywhere, so visibleChildren is not changed, this is the expected behaviour

Comment: @EstusFlask First time using Pinia so it's very possible that I'm misinterpreting something about it. Here's the scenario: the page has containers as children. When I move another container (originally not on the page) to the page, I would need the children to update to include the newly moved container. This happens but only after refresh. I'd like to find a way to update the children state. 1/2

Comment: @EstusFlask The difference between state.children and the getter VisibleChildren (as I intended it) was that children can contain not visible containers, whereas the getter visibleChildren only gets the containers with the propery visible equal to true. 2/2

Comment: Pinia is a thin wrapper around Vue reactive api so the same concepts apply. `getter` is a computed (not writable). If you need to change a computed, you change reactive data it's computed from. Currently the dependency is state.children. It's unknown in which way it's supposed to be updated, so nothing can be suggested as a fix

Comment: @EstusFlask thank you so much for the inputs, this made me realise a possible solution would be to push the moved container to state.children after the move event.

Comment: Depends on the implementation of ContainerCard, but likely the way to go

Comment: @EstusFlask It works. It would have taken longer to figure out without your inputs, I'd be happy to accept this as the correct answer if you fancy posting it.

Comment: Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pinia is a thin wrapper around Vue reactive api so the same concepts apply. Pinia getter is a readonly computed. If you need to change a computed, you change reactive data it's computed from. Currently the dependency is `state.children`, so it's `state.children` that needs to be changed in order to change `visibleChildren` and `children.value`.

Vue computeds are shallowly reactive, in order to recompute `visibleChildren`,  `this.children` array itself needs to be changed, changing `this.children[0].visible` won't do this.